# Deep-linking fails to set state in Angular-UI ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Please check out this terribly simple site of mine: http://gist1.perlmodules.net:8080/

It uses two states. While the last one is reachable by clicking on the links at the bottom of the page, if you attempt to reload the browser while there the views do not appear.

Shouldn't angular-ui ui-router display the views of deep-links?

Comment: It looks like you haven't set the parent state for the `site.funny` state. So add `parent: site` to the `site.funny` state object. I'd also have a read through [this tutorial](http://txt.fliglio.com/2013/05/angularjs-state-management-with-ui-router/) if you have any other problems. It explains everything very well.

Comment: I tried adding parent. Parent's not needed anyway, given that the name of my state contains a dot (parent is the first part of the name).

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question. The gist is gone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `<base href="/">` in the `<head>` section of my HTML, and that solved the problem.

To see the modified (and corrected) version, go here: http://gist2.perlmodules.net:8080/a/funny

This bug and it's solution is described here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/200#issuecomment-20932129

...and in the link at the bottom of that page.